# Why does material preview and EEVEE rendering appear just black?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I don't know why my material preview and render preview is looking transparent black like this despite that I have applied principled shader.

I made this scene in the morning and it was working just fine, I saved it but now when I opened it, I made no change but I still cannot view the texture and renders.

Please tell me how to fix this. It is a real problem to check if my color is correct. Yeah my solid display mode is fine. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQVYieRfQBY) by the way. Even rendering the image with EEVEE gives the same black result and I can only see the colors when rendering with cycles and my hardware isn't strong enough to do cycles all the time. Please help.

[image: screenshot showing black objects in material preview mode]

Comment: Is it possible the displacement is too strong, and the mesh is turning inside out?

Comment: Check if you didn't set **Alpha** input in Principled BSDF to 0.

Comment: But then none of the several objects are visible. I am facing this problem only with eevee and not cycles. And the scene was looking perfect yesterday but it is not working today. I want to render it with eevee but now it is not working and i cannot use cycle for the full render. Is that any issue with my hardware?

Comment: I was facing similar issue in V 3.2 I downgraded to v 2.80 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the information given:

- it's not hardware issue, because it worked earlier (unless you updated drivers)
- it's not a material issue, because it works in Cycles, *Material Output* is set to *All*, and you don't use Engine specific nodes
- It's not object settings, because multiple objects have the same problem

One important thing to test is to create a new project and see if the issue remains there. If not, this confirms it's not hardware issue. Additionally, you can open the problematic project, but in the *Open Dialog* settings disable *Load UI*:

[image]

My best guess so far is that you have *Strength of the studiolight* set to 0 - increase it:

[image]